# jQuery issues with .load() and PHP Forms

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am working on a project that has a main page, html, and 2 PHP pages. The way i'm dealing with this is via jQuery, with the command .load(). Here's how it looks like now:

```
    <script>
    $("#B").click(function(){
        $("#div2").load("agregarUsuario.php");
    });
    $("#eliminarUsuario").click(function(){
        $("#div2").load("eliminarUsuario.php");
    });

    </script>
```

So, when i hit any of the  with either id, A or B, it loads the php with no issues. Each on of the PHP has a submit form that looks like this:

```
require_once('empleado.inc');
        echo "  <form method='post' action=''>";
        echo "    <div id='username_input'>";
        echo "  <div id='username_inputleft'></div>";

        echo "  <div id='username_inputmiddle'>";

        echo "      <input type='text' name='usuario' id='url' value='Usuario' onclick='this.value = '''>";
        echo "      <img id='url_user' src='./images/mailicon.png' alt=''>";
        echo "  </div>";

        echo "  <div id='username_inputright'></div>";
        echo " </div>";

        echo " <div id='password_input'>";
        echo "  <div id='password_inputleft'></div>";

        echo "  <div id='password_inputmiddle'>";
        echo "      <input type='password' name='password' id='url' value='Password' onclick='this.value = '''>";
        echo "      <img id='url_password' src='./images/passicon.png' alt=''>";

        echo "  </div>";
        echo "  <div id='password_inputright'></div>";
        echo " </div>";

        echo " <div id='submit'>";
        //echo "    <input type='image' src='./images/submit_hover.png' id='submit1' value='Entrar' name='Entrar'>";
        //echo "    <input type='image' src='./images/submit.png' id='submit2' value='Entrar' name='Entrar'>";
        echo "<input type='submit'  value='Entrar' class='button' name='Entrar'>";
        echo " </div>";

        echo " <div id='links_left'></div>";
        echo " <div id='links_right'></div>";

    echo " </div>"; 
    echo "  </form>";

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        $Empleado = new empleado();
        $Empleados= $Empleado->consultar();

        $Fila=$Empleados->fetch_assoc();

       if ((isset ($_POST['Entrar']))&&($Fila['Contrasena']===base64_encode($_POST['password'])&&($Fila['Nombre']===$_POST['usuario']))){
          $_SESSION['usuario']=$_POST['usuario'];
          header ("Location:  http://localhost/Ferreteria/adminIndex.php");

      }else{
              echo "<B>NO tiene permisos</B>";
       }
    }
```

Something simple: just collecting data and submitting to the database. That's the way we've been taught to. Now, here's the problem. Each one of the PHP forms works fine, separately. However, when i load them in the main html and submit them, any of them, they just reload the main page and don't submit the action.

I'm a novice on this and i've tested the php several times. As i have pointed out, the work fine separately on the web browser (Chrome) but the action is not submitted or done once i test them on the main page. Am i missing something after the .load()?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to `echo` everything in PHP... you can close php with `?>` and then write plain HTML, then open PHP again with `<?php`

But about your question: the reason nothing happens is because of this:

```
<form method='post' action=''>
```

The `action=''` means that the form will `POST` back to the same URL that you are currently on. If your URL is `www.example.com/test.php` and you load a form with ajax, if `action=''` then it will `POST` back to the same URL (`<form method='post' action=''>`) instead of the PHP file where you need it to.

**So in `agregarUsuario.php` you need:**

```
<form method='post' action='./agregarUsuario.php'>
```

**And in `eliminarUsuario.php` you need:**

```
<form method='post' action='./eliminarUsuario.php'>
```

Comment: That's partially working @degenerate. Once i set the action to those PHP, the browser directs me there. I'm using .load from jquery instead of Frames and i need to have form working without leaving the main page. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: If you don't want to `POST` directly to the PHP pages then you need to include the PHP files with `if ($_POST) include('agregarUsuario.php');` on your main page -- but then you are just going in circles. There is no reason to include the files with jquery in the first place...